# I want to extract a words after a fix combination of words and special character also need a count of extracted words in particular cell

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, regex, apply, regex-lookarounds

I have one data frame df which has one column.
I want to extract a words after a fix combination of words & special character, also need a count of extracted words in that particular cell.

For example:  (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'Tilt Sensor',(Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'Hello world',(Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'ABC',

Now from above line I want to extract any words in between commas after "(Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':"

So, in that case I want only 'Tilt Sensor' and **its count in that particular cell.**

I don't need 'Hello world' or 'ABC' as it comes 2nd or 3rd. Basically I want first search words.

Below is my df:-

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



data = {'product_name': ["[{'name':'Trigger Cause Status (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'Tilt Sensor','packetType':'enumerated','leastSigBit':440,,'Tilt Sensor','mostSigBit':447},{'name':'User Set Year (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)', (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'Band','valueNumber':2022.0,'units':'Undefined / Not Used','packetType':'Tilt Sensor','leastSigBit':432,'mostSigBit':439},{'name':'User Set Month,(Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'Back space',{'name':'User Set Minute (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueNumber':16.0,'units':'min','packetType':'unsigned','leastSigBit':400,'mostSigBit':407},'Tilt Sensor',{'name':'User Set Second (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueNumber':36.0,'units':'s','packetType':'unsigned','leastSigBit':392,'mostSigBit':399}]",
                         "[{'name':'Trigger Cause Status (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'Volumetric Sensor','packetType':'enumerated','leastSigBit':440,'mostSigBit':447},{'name':'User Set Year (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueNumber':2022.0,'units':'(Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'Being human','packetType':'unsigned','leastSigBit':432,'mostSigBit':439},{'name':'User Set Month (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueNumber':6.0,'(Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'Hello'':'Month','Volumetric Sensor','packetType':'unsigned','leastSigBit':424,'mostSigBit':431},{'name':'User Set Day (Most Recent Alarm ]"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

I tried regex or apply method but not getting what I want.

Below are some code which I have tried,

```
df["Extract"] = df["product_name"].apply(lambda st: st[st.find("(Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':")+1:st.find(",")])

df['Title'] = df.product_name.str.extract(r'"(Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'"\s*([^\.]*)\s*\.', expand=False)
```

Below is my expected result:

```
data = {'product_name': ["[{'name':'Trigger Cause Status (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'Tilt Sensor','packetType':'enumerated','leastSigBit':440,,'Tilt Sensor','mostSigBit':447},{'name':'User Set Year (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)', (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'Band','valueNumber':2022.0,'units':'Undefined / Not Used','packetType':'Tilt Sensor','leastSigBit':432,'mostSigBit':439},{'name':'User Set Month,(Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'Back space',{'name':'User Set Minute (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueNumber':16.0,'units':'min','packetType':'unsigned','leastSigBit':400,'mostSigBit':407},'Tilt Sensor',{'name':'User Set Second (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueNumber':36.0,'units':'s','packetType':'unsigned','leastSigBit':392,'mostSigBit':399}]",
                             "[{'name':'Trigger Cause Status (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'Volumetric Sensor','packetType':'enumerated','leastSigBit':440,'mostSigBit':447},{'name':'User Set Year (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueNumber':2022.0,'units':'(Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'Being human','packetType':'unsigned','leastSigBit':432,'mostSigBit':439},{'name':'User Set Month (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueNumber':6.0,'(Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'Hello'':'Month','Volumetric Sensor','packetType':'unsigned','leastSigBit':424,'mostSigBit':431},{'name':'User Set Day (Most Recent Alarm ]"],
       'Extarct': ['Tilt Sensor','Volumetric Sensor'],'Count': [4,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be as follows:

- Use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to get the first match between `\'valueString\':\'` and `\',`.
- Next, use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with a lambda function for each row (`axis=1`) to get a count for each value now stored in `df.Extract` inside the appropriate `product_name` string.

```
import pandas as pd

# also adding the string from your comment
data = {'product_name': ["[{'name':'Trigger Cause Status (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'Tilt Sensor','packetType':'enumerated','leastSigBit':440,,'Tilt Sensor','mostSigBit':447},{'name':'User Set Year (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)', (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'Band','valueNumber':2022.0,'units':'Undefined / Not Used','packetType':'Tilt Sensor','leastSigBit':432,'mostSigBit':439},{'name':'User Set Month,(Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'Back space',{'name':'User Set Minute (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueNumber':16.0,'units':'min','packetType':'unsigned','leastSigBit':400,'mostSigBit':407},'Tilt Sensor',{'name':'User Set Second (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueNumber':36.0,'units':'s','packetType':'unsigned','leastSigBit':392,'mostSigBit':399}]",
                         "[{'name':'Trigger Cause Status (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'Volumetric Sensor','packetType':'enumerated','leastSigBit':440,'mostSigBit':447},{'name':'User Set Year (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueNumber':2022.0,'units':'(Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'Being human','packetType':'unsigned','leastSigBit':432,'mostSigBit':439},{'name':'User Set Month (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueNumber':6.0,'(Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'Hello'':'Month','Volumetric Sensor','packetType':'unsigned','leastSigBit':424,'mostSigBit':431},{'name':'User Set Day (Most Recent Alarm ]",
                         "[{'name':'Power Mode Quality Factor','valueString':'Power Mode Undefined','valueString':'Finally',Trigger Cause Status (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'No Trigger (Event Store Empty)',}]"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Extract'] = df.product_name.str.extract(
    r'\(Most Recent Alarm Trigger\)\',\'valueString\':\'(.*?)\',')
# N.B. We're using the question mark to make the search for '.*' lazy

df['Count'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.product_name.count(row.Extract), axis=1)

print(df.iloc[:,1:])

                          Extract  Count
0                     Tilt Sensor      4
1               Volumetric Sensor      2
2  No Trigger (Event Store Empty)      1
```

N.B. If it is possible for `str.extract` to find no match, you'll end up with `NaN` values in `df.Extract`. If so, this will cause an error for `df.apply(lambda row: row.product_name.count(row.Extract), axis=1)` (since it is expecting a `string`). To avoid this, you could use:

```
df['Count'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.product_name.count(row.Extract) 
                       if isinstance(row.Extract,str) else 0, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But it is partially correct just because I want extract after mentioned particular word which is "(Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':".
You have only considered "valueString" because of this it is giving wrong result.

Comment: in this case 
[{'name':'Power Mode Quality Factor','valueString':'Power Mode Undefined','valueString':'Finally',Trigger Cause Status (Most Recent Alarm Trigger)','valueString':'No Trigger (Event Store Empty)',}]

I want "No Trigger (Event Store Empty)" as my extracted word.

Comment: Should work now, no? See the update.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75206298/how-can-i-convert-column-a-in-to-column-b-with-some-condition-in-python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76768798/19812003

@ouroboros1 can you please help?