# Stuck in regex condition in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a data frame column technician_verbatim which contain text.

```
data = {'technician_verbatim': ["not leak not secured not fitted not parameter"]}
    
Delta_Claims = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I have variable tmp_list which contain some word of list.
tmp_list = ['leak', "secu", "fitt", "para", "secur", "fitte", "param"]

I have another df not_no_without_exceptions which is a bag of words.

```
data = {'not_exceptions': ["secure","secured","fit","fitted"]}

not_no_without_exceptions = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now I have written a code to remove those words from technician_verbatim which are after not. for example [not accepted, not sober, not tight, not loose] but if the word after not is available in not_exceptions column then it should not remove with not.

tmp_list is a list of words which is available in technician_verbatim after not. I have pulled only 4 and 5 alphabets after not.

so in my above case "secu", "fitt", "secur", "fitte" this words are matching with not_exceptions list. so they will be remain there in technician_verbatim.
final output will be: "not secured not fitted"

my expected output:

```
data = {'New_technician_verbatim': ["not secured not fitted"]}
        
    Delta_Claims = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Below is my whole code which I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

Delta_Claims = pd.read_csv('C:\\path\\hybrid_iqm - Copy.csv')

not_no_without_exceptions = pd.read_csv('C:\\path\\not_no_without_exceptions.csv')

not_exceptions = not_no_without_exceptions['not_exceptions'].tolist()


tmp_list = ['leak', "secu", "fitt", "para", "secur", "fitte", "param"]

tmp_list = [f'{word.strip()}' for words in tmp_list for word in words.split()]



# Create a copy of the technician_verbatim column to avoid modifying the original DataFrame
tmp_container_verb = Delta_Claims['technician_verbatim'].copy()

def remove_words(row):
    for i in tmp_list:
        if i not in not_exceptions:
            escaped_i = re.escape(i)
#               Updated pattern to match partial words with spaces or word boundaries before and after
            pattern = rf'\bnot\s+{escaped_i}\s*|\b{escaped_i}\s*'
#             pattern = rf'not\s+{escaped_i}\s*|{escaped_i}\s*'

            row = re.sub(pattern, '', row, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return row

# Apply the remove_words function to each row in tmp_container_verb
Delta_Claims['tmp_container_verb'] = tmp_container_verb.apply(remove_words)

# Now tmp_container_verb contains the modified technician_verbatim values
print(Delta_Claims)
```

I don't understand, what's wrong with this line why it is not removing partial match (not parameter) it only remove "not param" and remain "eter"

```
pattern = rf'\bnot\s+{escaped_i}\s*|\b{escaped_i}\s*'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options.

Either pre-filter `tmp_list` to remove the words that match any word in `not_no_without_exceptions`, then craft a pattern and [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
import re

tmp_list2 = [w for w in tmp_list if not
             any(w2.startswith(w) for w2 in
             not_no_without_exceptions['not_exceptions'])]
pattern = fr"not ({'|'.join(map(re.escape, tmp_list2))})\w*\b\s*"
# '(not (?:secure|secured|fit|fitted)\w*\b)'

Delta_Claims['New_technician_verbatim'] = (Delta_Claims['technician_verbatim']
                                           .str.replace(pattern, '', regex=True)
                                          )
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PvaKZ2/1)

---

Or, don't use the list of words and only [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) the words from `not_no_without_exceptions` (and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them):

```
import re

pattern = f'(not (?:{"|".join(map(re.escape, not_no_without_exceptions["not_exceptions"]))})\w*\b)'
# 'not (leak|para|param)\w*\b\s*'

Delta_Claims['New_technician_verbatim'] = (Delta_Claims['technician_verbatim']
                                           .str.extractall(pattern)[0]
                                           .groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)
                                          )
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OmRLyR/1)

---

Output:

```
                             technician_verbatim New_technician_verbatim
0  not leak not secured not fitted not parameter  not secured not fitted
```

Comment: You're welcome, so which of the two approaches did you use?

Comment: First one is working fine for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76926809/not-able-to-figure-out-where-i-am-doing-mistake

Answer (score 0):

Only change this line:- `pattern = rf'\bnot\s+{escaped_i}\s*|\b{escaped_i}\s*'`

to this:-

```
pattern = rf'not\s+{escaped_i}\S*\s*|not\s+{escaped_i}\S*\s*\w+'
```